# How to pass a C# variable as a parameter in a http call to a php script

Tags: c#, php

In my C# app I can successfully insert data into my database but the data is hardcoded in my php script. This is my http call to my php script in my app:

```
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://10.0.2.2/testinsert.php");
```

I know locally I can pass variables locally like this:

```
localhost/testinsert.php?Name=bob&age=50
```

If my data gets user input for the name and age I would need to store them in variables and then pass those variables but how would I do that? I saw something where they did this but it doesn't work:

```
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://10.0.2.2/testinsert.php?Name=" . var_name . "&Age=" . var_age);
```

Comment: It seems to me you are mixing PHP and C# syntax. Which do you want to use at the problem side?

Comment: So in the example you use, you are doing a get request. Your PHP script will be able to read them using $_GET. So in your PHP script they would be available as $_GET["Name"] and $_GET["Age"]. 

If this is your problem? Or is your issue with setting the values in the request string in c#? Please try to clearify your question

Comment: Try using string interpolation: `$"http://10.0.2.2/testinsert.php?Name={var_name}&Age={var_age}"`

Comment: Use [String interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) or [string concatenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings)

Comment: String manipulation is one of the very first things you learn when learning c#... the `.` is php syntax not c#

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate:

```
"http://10.0.2.2/testinsert.php?Name=" + var_name + "&Age=" + var_age
```

Or use interpolation

```
$"http://10.0.2.2/testinsert.php?Name={var_name}&Age={var_age}"
```

But in both cases you'll need to be cautious about escaping characters and the potential for URL injection issues.

Comment: Also learn about [idempotency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Examples_2). Assuming that `testinsert` actually inserts something you'll want to require a `POST`, not `GET`.

Comment: @RobIII - correct - assuming it is an API that intends to follow the HTTP specification, rather than one of the multitude that subverts it.